# Closing a question - only option for another site is Robotics Meta

Tags: feature-request, support, status-bydesign

I tried to vote to close [this question on image processing](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/how-can-i-recognize-animals-in-a-video-stream-or-static-images-with-opencv-or-ot), but when I clicked, "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" the only option I could select was the Robotics Meta. It wasn't a question about Electronics, Arduino, or Raspberry Pi, so I didn't choose that option.

Is there a way to "write in" another site in the SE network? I would like to have redirected the OP to the computer science board but that wasn't an option.

Comment: Funnily enough, I have just asked the same question on SE Arduino meta, a few days ago: [Why does the migrate dialog only list Arduino Meta?](http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/why-does-the-migrate-dialog-only-list-arduino-meta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Migrating to an arbitrary stack exchange site

This is only an option for ♦ moderators, so instead of voting to close the question <sup>†</sup> you should flag it for moderator attention <sup>‡</sup> with a suggestion of where it should be migrated.

On established sites, migration paths are created to allow migration without moderator approval, but any migrations outside of those pathways still have to be handled by a moderator. The reason for this is because...

#### This specific question

This question would not be a good candidate for migration. We try not to migrate questions which would just be closed on the target site for another reason. In this case, it is a very broad question. It could be edited to be a more *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems faced](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* but that may invalidate the existing answer, which is pretty good, given the limitations of the question.

If neither [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) nor [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) want this question, I'm happy for it to remain on *robitics*, since there are robotic applications of the answer to this question.

† <sub>*close > off-topic because... > This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*</sub>

‡ <sub>*flag >  in need of moderator intervention*</sub>

Comment: I feel like the question linked applies to robotics in the same way that a question about microcontroller PC drivers might apply, or hardware bus timing might apply, or artificial intelligence might apply. That is, while they are all related to robotics, the robotics SE might not be the *best* site for the OP to get a fast, good answer. The question wasn't closed on our site so I'm not sure why it would be closed on another site.

Comment: Thanks @Chuck, the rules have some flexibility in them. Sometimes an excessively broad question can still be redeemed by a sufficiently useful broad answer, which I think was warranted in this case. The only reason I didn't close it was that it already had a good, accepted answer by the time I saw it, which is incidentally the same reason why the moderators of the other sites didn't want to migrate it. It is still possible that another moderator will close it, or it will attract enough close votes to be closed by the community, but I don't feel the need to act any further on this now.