# Why does the "duplicate question" close reason restrict to Robotics SE only?

Tags: support, close-reasons, migration, exact-duplicates

If a question is a duplicate from another StackExchange site, when you try to close the question as a duplicate, it only allows you to select the duplicate question from within Robotics.StackExchange.  We often get duplicates from [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/), [RaspberryPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), and [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).  So it would be great if this restriction was lifted.

For example, I wanted to close [this question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/22959/how-do-i-create-an-s-curve-profile-for-a-robot-to-move) as a duplicate.  But I had to choose the "Off topic - Other" reason and enter the dupe link in a comment.

The consensus from [this other question about the same topic](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/closing-a-question-only-option-for-another-site-is-robotics-meta) seemed to be about migrating the question.  But what if it is already cross-posted?  Should we still flag to migrate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short and sweet answer is - because, while we're a network of sites, each site is an island and **there's no expectation that questions can or should only be answered on one site**. In fact, if a question is in scope for two different sites, there's no reason* the question shouldn't be answered on both. There may be slightly different areas of expertise that will create rich answers on both sites.

* So, technically, there's one reason - we don't like it when one user posts the same question on more than one site - "cross posting" - but this is more of an exception. We prefer that a user choose which site to ask their question or, if the question can be reframed to specifically address concepts that each community can address. This is discussed in [this Meta Stack Exchange question and its answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

In the end, if the question is on topic and wasn't a case of the same user mindlessly plopping the question on several sites - **don't** close it! If it can be a valuable resource for the people using this site, let it exist here, too.